# If $p$ & $q$ are eigenvalues of $A$ & $B$ respectively, then are $p+q$ & $pq$ that of $A+B$ & $AB$ respectively?

Tags: linear-algebra

I really can't get it, either a proof or a way to disprove. Suppose $AB=BA$? Does this result hold then? Here, $A$ & $B$ are any $n\times n$ matrices.

If so then how? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For $A+B$, say $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.  Is $3$ an e-value of $A+B$?

Secondly,  using the same $A$ and $B$, say.  $AB=0$.  Hence $2\cdot1$ is not an e-value...

Comment: is there  any condition under which the above is true?

Comment: I guess if $A$ and $B$ were the identity matrix, off the top of my head...  maybe even multiples of the identity.   I'd guess there might be other examples (where it's true).

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ were e-values with a _common_ e-vector,  say.

Comment: this means commutativity of A &B also fails to have the above property?

Comment: It won't always have it.  Notice in my example above $A$ and $B$ commute.   In fact $AB=BA=0$.

Comment: yes @ChrisCuster, thnx